# c# use quotes in App.config to run batch

Tags: c#, app-config, double-quotes

I have an issue with using double quotes. From my application I need to execute a 3rd party batchfile. This bacthfile takes parameters that include double quotes.
The bacthfile:

```
\\\\myserver\data\program\mainprog.exe -username"martin" -password"abc123"
```

I have added the location of this file to my App.config. I can''t put the quotes in there, nor can I use escapes, so I used # insead:

```
[ add key="mBatch" value="\\myserver\data\program\mainprog.exe -username#martin# -password#abc123#" /]
```

After reading this key I replace the # as followed:

```
_settings = new AppSettings();
_settings.batch = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mBatch").ToString();
_settings.batch = _settings.batch.Replace(@"\", "\\");
_settings.batch = _settings.batch.Replace("#", "\"");
```

When I print _settings.batch it looks perfect.

Next I try to run the batch:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = _settings.batch; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Start();
```

This results in an error indicating that the path cannot be found.
If I put the contents of _settings.batch in a text field, copy-paste it and run it, it works, so the path and parameters are correct.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass the arguments in `StartInfo.Arguments`, not in the `Filename` property, or is that different using `UseShellExecute=true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides your quoting problem: you must assign

```
 \\\\myserver\data\program\mainprog.exe
```

to

```
 proc.StartInfo.FileName
```

and

```
 -username"martin" -password"abc123"
```

to

```
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments
```

That's why you got the path error. So either make this two separated entries in your App.config, or add some code to split the parts when initializing the `ProcessStartInfo` object. But beware, the exe file path can contain spaces, you have to deal with that case.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I simply wasted time looking at the quotes, the problem was exactly what you stated. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

To proper way to use double quote in app.config is to use encode quotes in XML, that is `&quot;`.

So, you can use `value="\\myserver\data\program\mainprog.exe -username &quot;martin&quot; -password &quot;abc123&quot;"` instead of `value="\\myserver\data\program\mainprog.exe -username#martin# -password#abc123#"`

Please note that I add a space `' '` after `-username` and `-password`.

Comment: Thanks, looks much better and removes the need for the replace function.